# Mirage Board: Nodes with additional brackets over them

Tags: world-of-final-fantasy

In the mirage board, it can be seen that some nodes are marked with additional brackets around them. What does this signify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets around nodes mean that an ability is exclusive to the Mirage, and won't be shared with any other form of the Mirage.

Reading [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/168651-world-f-final-fantasy/74488950):

> Abilities with a circle bracket(like Special moves) around them ARE NOT shared between any monsters.
>
> Every other node is shared between monsters on the same mirage board. So if they show up together when you try and level them up, they all get the effects.

It seems confirmed in this [other thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/WorldOfFinalFantasy/comments/5c3c8h/im_confused_on_how_the_cross_skills_work/):

> When you go into the mirage boards, look at which monsters appear in boxes on the same screen. When you bring up the ability list, all the powers in white will be shared among all the forms that appear in boxes together. The powers listed in green apply only to that single form. (In the sphere grids, **brackets around a node represent the green, exclusive powers**.)